# inDesign Script to "when textbox created paste clipboard content in it"

Tags: adobe-indesign, indesign-scripting, javascript

I have no experience with scripting, but I can maybe explain what the intented script should do:

1. Select text, cut it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> after `mouseUp`.
2. Make textbox (manually). Drag with mouse, if possible "toggle" the hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> function to draw same x,y valued box.
3. Check if box is created then paste text inside it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>

Rough idea of what I could find on the forums so far:

```
app.selection[0].endHorizontalOffset - app.selection[0].horizontalOffset
var textBox = app.selection[0].textFrames.add();
textBox.geometricBounds[];
app.select(ip, SelectionOptions.REPLACE_WITH);
textBox.contents = app.paste();
```

My job requires to do this a tedious number of times, possibly leading to repetitive strain injury.

Comment: If the text frame is to be drawn manually, what possible benefit would a script contain over simply using keyboard shortcuts to copy/draw frame/paste ? The "repetitive strain injury" comment seems a bit hyperbolic. Thousands do this, and have been doing this for years without such issues. You're more likely to develop issues using a mouse than copy/pasting.

Comment: If there might be a way to make this automated, why not? It doesn't justify "have been doing this for years" in my opinion, can help speed up the process.

Comment: My point is, you are essentially looking to script ... copy... paste... All I'm asking is *how* a script would be faster than merely using two keyboard shortcuts. At the very most.... a script would reduce things to 1 keyboard shortcut while running slower overall.

Comment: I would not have to need to use the keyboard and 2/3 fingers to do the shortcuts (those that are also in a bad position), making me remove 2/3 more clicks every text I have to add. Also the "hold alt" to make the box W/H better is another button I would remove from my hand strain.
If we have the tecnology to make it easier/ faster to use (using only the mouse), won't be a problem to use it.

Comment: I don’t think there is a way to do this. You could make a script that runs at a shortcut key and pastes the clipboard content into the selected text frame, but as Scott says, that would just be trading Ctrl + V for a different shortcut (or mouse click) to run the script. You could perhaps save a tiny bit of work by making a script that cuts selected text and inserts it into a new text frame, which you can then resize manually – but that’s also a very minor improvement over simply doing Ctrl + X, escape, Ctrl + C, resize new frame.

Comment: Not sure I understand completely. But if I do understand you, I think I have similar issue when making magazines. I receive all text for an article in one text document. But captions and aside boxes must have their own text frames, so I have to: *select text, cut, escape text frame, paste, apply object style, resize*. That's 3 keyboard shortcuts, 2 mouse drags and one mouse click. That could be reduced to: *select text, click script, resize*. I can see the idea in eliminating those 3 keyboard shortcuts. The object style can in some cases contain the wanted dimensions. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually looking more into it, I'm not sure I would bother making a script for this. I roughly estimate that I might save 1-3 seconds per text frame so I could perhaps save 2-10 minutes on one magazine. But I would have to make the script and make variations of it for each object style I need. Each job might require its own set of scripts which I must maintain and locate at the beginning of each job. Not sure it's worth it.

Comment: My work is more toward what @Wolff said. I still think that automating it will indeed save time (1s per text is a lot when you add up the quantity of texts) and my fingers will thank me on the later run. 
After evaluating all the comments, I find that a Script is not what I was looking for (If I got it correct, you have to find the script and apply it to every single file you do, it's not something global, making it waste time instead of saving).

Comment: I already made a AHK script that makes the _"Hold Alt while LClick"_ for the same sized TextBoxes and it helped me a lot saving time and the possibility to press Alt at the wrong time, making so that I have to fix the textbox. Maybe what I need is another AHK macro that do: _"after mouseUP, cut"_ and _"after making box, paste"_. 
Thank you once again for enlightening me as to why a Script would not be the best choice and all your comments are somewhat valid (not for my case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got an Auto Hotkey macro to do what I needed and it indeed saved me a lot of time, Script was a bad idea. Won't publish it here since it's not related to the inDesign Scripts.